# SQL: How find newest row for each value of some column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to find the newest `message` entry for each `chat_id`.

For example, for this table I need to get list of rows: with id=`1c6bad12` for `chat_id`=`ee5152ff` and with `id`=`e4485bdf` for `chat_id`=`29cc7217`. (2th and 6th).

| id | chat_id | created_at | text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1442a8e8 | ee5152ff | 2023-01-09 12:38:44.237280 | hello1 |
| 1c6bad12 | ee5152ff | 2023-05-09 10:39:25.260409 | hello3 |
| 514c2db5 | 29cc7217 | 2023-02-14 09:05:20.284902 | qwerty1 |
| c4247480 | ee5152ff | 2023-01-14 19:05:20.284902 | hello2 |
| e4485bdf | 29cc7217 | 2023-06-14 11:05:20.284902 | qwerty2 |

Now I have only such query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM message
ORDER BY created_at DESC, id DESC;
```

But it reruns all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query returns all rows because only what it does is ordering.

Since you want to return one row per `chat_id` you can use `DISTINCT ON` (Note that column that you want to use in `DISTINCT ON` must be as initial column in `ORDER BY`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (chat_id) *
FROM message
ORDER BY chat_id, created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the window function `row_number()` to assign an incrimented id for each record grouped by **chat_id** and ordered by **created_at** :

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by chat_id order by created_at desc ) as rn
  from message
) as s
where rn = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rgvJJKyM)

Answer (score 0):

I created your table guessing VARCHAR(255) for all the string values and TIMESTAMP for the date / time field. This seems to work.

```
select chat_id, max(created_at) from message group by chat_id;
```

Comment: OP, needs to get the message text well, which isn't possible in this scenario due to the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes in that case my solution won't work.